# MikroORM Create filter query based on a value in the database

Tags: mikro-orm

Simply put, is it possible to create a filter query where I reference a value stored in the row?

For example:

```js
orm.em.findOne(Job, {
   status: 'active',
   startDate: {
     $gt: '$anotherDateField'
   }
}
```

My goal is to have a user-input defined filter (the status), but also only bring back certain rows where the start date is greater than another column's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom SQL fragment

```
orm.em.findOne(Job, {
   status: 'active',
   // expr helper allows to escape strict typing of the method, so we can use `em.raw()`
   [expr('startDate')]: {
     $gt: orm.em.raw('another_date_field') // this will have to be column name, not property name
   }
}
```

Note that your `em` needs to be typed to the one exported from driver package to have access to the `em.raw()` method (if you work with `orm` instance, you need to type that to `MikroORM<YourDriver>` so `orm.em` can be properly typed).

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager/#using-custom-sql-fragments

Comment: Thanks for the insanely quick reply. I'm using a helper function to generate the filter query so don't have access to the underlying `em` as its dealing with a complicated json  field query. On an off-chance, is this possible without the reference to `em`? If not I'll just pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: You could try wrapping it in parens so the ORM sees it as a custom expression, e.g. `$gt: '(another_date_field)'`. Not sure if that works, havent tried

Comment: I seem to have some trouble getting the em with access to `raw`. I am injecting: `orm: MikroORM<PostgreSqlDriver>`, yet `raw` does not exist on `orm.em` (mikro-orm 4.5.9, mikro-orm psql 4.5.9).

Comment: I resolved this by using `getKnex` on the EntityManager. This now seems to be generating the correct SQL, even with JSON fields. Thank you very much.

Comment: I see, `em.raw()` is v5 only, but its just a shortcut